# Is it OK to ask for thoughts on / experience with <game-relevant middleware>?

Tags: discussion

Say for instance, I want to implement something into a game that seems to be doable judging by public information/advertising of a certain middleware package, but I'm sensing trouble down the road when things get more intrigued - is it alright to ask for specifics about that middleware product?

Questions might be along the lines of:

- "Does <middleware> allow for an easy way to provide custom memory allocation?"
- "Does <middleware> rely heavily on callbacks?"
- "Does <middleware> lend itself well to being used in job systems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Faq: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”

So for your 3 example questions, I would say 1 and 2 are answerable questions.  3 is a bit more subjective without more details.

And of course if said middleware is under NDA you're probably not going to get answers.

Comment: Thanks! In the NDA-case I might at least find out that it *is* in fact under NDA :)

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could simply add a comment to Tetrad's answer, but I don't have enough street cred yet ;)

There's not just NDAs, sometimes it's not practical to do honest reviews with negative sides if the company you're working for has a business deal with said middleware company (don't forget that you have companies that own many middlewares and tools used throughout the industry, I won't name the company but most people know who I'm talking about), as it might make them unhappy, especially if your username can be linked to your real name and the company you work for!

Comment: That is a problem indeed. Thanks for mentioning, though!